# Retrieving metrics through librado using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, librato

Good morning!

I'm having troubles trying to get a single number from `librato` to use in a html page.

I just want to get the last value of the metric `AWS.Billing.EstimatedCharges.total`, the name of the client that spent that value and put it all together in a HTML page (simple, but not to me)

I'm trying to use this API https://github.com/goodeggs/librato-node
And I still not figured out how to solve this problem.

ps: I cannot use the embed chart.

```
var http = require('http'); 
http.createServer(function (req, res) { }).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1"); 
console.log('Server running at 127.0.0.1:1337/'); 
var librato = require('librato-node'); 
api = librato.configure({email: 'myemail', token: 'mytoken'}); 
librato.start(); process.once('SIGINT', function() { librato.stop(); 
// stop optionally takes a callback }); 
// Don't forget to specify an error handler, otherwise errors will be thrown
librato.on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); });
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you show what you have tried in code please

Comment: var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {


    }).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');


var librato = require('librato-node');

api = librato.configure({email: 'myemail', token: 'mytoken'});
librato.start();

process.once('SIGINT', function() {
  librato.stop(); // stop optionally takes a callback
});

// Don't forget to specify an error handler, otherwise errors will be thrown
librato.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});

Comment: after this point I dont know what to do

Comment: this code basically up the server and makes the conection to the librato service

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install librato-metrics`, there's a lot of guessing here so please report back }8*)

```
const client = require('librato-metrics').createClient(
{
  email: process.env.LIBRATO_METRICS_EMAIL,
  token: process.env.LIBRATO_METRICS_TOKEN
}


  const payload = {
    count: 1,
    resolution: 60
  };

  client.get('/metrics/AWS.Billing.EstimatedCharges.total', payload,
    function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err, payload);            
      } else {
        console.log(response);

      }
    });
```

```